# How to encode a string to replace all special characters

Tags: java, android

I have a string which contains special character. But I have to convert the string into a string without having any special character so I used Base64 But in Base64 we are using equals to symbol (=) which is a special character. But I want to convert the string into a string which will have only alphanumerical letters. Also I can't remove special character only i have to replace all the special characters to maintain unique between two different strings. How to achieve this, Which encoding will help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option would be to encode the text to binary using UTF-8, and then convert the binary back to text as hex (two characters per byte). It won't be terribly efficient, but it *will* just be alphanumeric.

You could use base32 instead to be a bit more efficient, but that's likely to be significantly more work, unless you can find a library which supports it out of the box. (Libraries to perform hex encoding are very common.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of variations of base64, some of which don't use padding.  (You still have a couple of non-alphanumeric characters for characters 62 and 63.)

The Wikipedia page on [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) goes into the details, including the "standard" variations used for a number of common use-cases.  (Does yours match one of those?)

If your strings have to be strictly alphanumeric, then you'll need to use hex encoding (one byte becomes 2 hex digits), or roll your own encoding scheme.   Your stated requirements are rather unusual ...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a regular expression to match all nonalphanumeric characters and replace them with an empty string.

```js
// This will remove all special characters except space.
var cleaned = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s]/gm, '')
```

Adding any special characters to the above regex will skip that character.

```
// This will remove all special characters except space and period.
var cleaned = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s.]/gm, '')
```

A working example.

```js
const regex = /[^\w\s]/gm;
const str = `This is a text with many special characters.
Hello, user, your password is 543#!\$32=!`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Regex explained.

```
[^\w\s]/gm
Match a single character not present in the list below [^\w\s]
\w matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v \u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff])

Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Comment: Link seems to be broken

Comment: @TorstenSimon added another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Commons codec has a url safe version of base64, which emits - and _ instead of + and / characters

http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafe(byte[])

Answer (score 0):

If you truly can only use alphanumerical characters you will have to come up with an escaping scheme that uses one of those chars for example, use 0 as the escape, and then encode the special char as a 2 char hex encoding of the ascii.  Use 000 to mean 0.

e.g.

```
This is my special sentence with a 0.
```

encodes to:

```
This020is020my020special020sentence020with020a02000002e
```